# пишу приложение для вк помогите разобраться

Tags: javascript, jquery, вконтакте

https://javascript.ru/forum/showthread.php?p=485352#post485352

при нажатии на кнопку показать друзей в ответет от сервера возвращает респонс

```
jQuery2200355515632236987_1526378888772({
  "response": {
    "count": 3,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 481313066,
        "first_name": "Карина",
        "last_name": "Михеева",
        "photo_100": "https://pp.userapi.com/c847018/v847018809/4d95e/SePLqNK1W8c.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 481315697,
        "first_name": "Анастасия",
        "last_name": "Миронова",
        "photo_100": "https://pp.userapi.com/c834402/v834402732/10c6b9/VsDTAfYYD0o.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 481434772,
        "first_name": "Вера",
        "last_name": "Виртик",
        "deactivated": "banned",
        "photo_100": "https://vk.com/images/deactivated_100.png"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

вобщем мне нужно чтобы выводились друзья с аватарками и именами на моем сайте!

P.S. для тестов этого кода сгенерируйте себе новый токен вк апи

Comment: Вопрос, заданный на форуме, всё ещё актуален: что не получается-то? Берёте эти данные и составляете из них HTML-элементы как вам нужно.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Пройдитесь циклом по полученному результату, используя [createElement](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) и [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild),

```js
var data = {
  "response": {
    "count": 3,
    "items": [{
        "id": 481313066,
        "first_name": "Карина",
        "last_name": "Михеева",
        "photo_100": "https://pp.userapi.com/c847018/v847018809/4d95e/SePLqNK1W8c.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 481315697,
        "first_name": "Анастасия",
        "last_name": "Миронова",
        "photo_100": "https://pp.userapi.com/c834402/v834402732/10c6b9/VsDTAfYYD0o.jpg"
      },
      {
        "id": 481434772,
        "first_name": "Вера",
        "last_name": "Виртик",
        "deactivated": "banned",
        "photo_100": "https://vk.com/images/deactivated_100.png"
      }
    ]
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < data.response.count; i++) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.style.width = '200px';
  d.style.height = '100px';
  d.style.background = 'gray';
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.style.width = '50px';
  image.style.height = '50px';
  d.appendChild(image);
  image.setAttribute('src', data.response.items[i].photo_100);
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = data.response.items[i].first_name;
  d.appendChild(p);
  document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

Comment: отлично ! спасибо большое

Comment: @ДенисЕвсеев, если ответ вас устраивает, то отметьте его галочкой.